# could not connect to local host

Tags: tomcat6

Recently i installed apache tomcat 6 on my PC.I started the server and try to open the tomcat manager using the url:

http://localhost:8081/manager/html

8081 is the connector port i used at the time of installation and no other services using this port.But its shows the error like

Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:8081

I used this with differnt browsers IE and crome but still getting the same error
Please provide me the solving to getrid of this.

Comment: Did you try to turn the server ON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the "Test your Install" section [here](http://www.michael-thomas.com/tech/apache/tomcat/tutorial_firststeps_tomcat/index.htm).

Answer (score 0):

first make sure the your server is running correctly by connect to http://localhost:8081/

Comment: server is on and still getting the error could not connect to localhost:8081

Comment: how do you know that the server is running ??